# How can I extend other module's types in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am writing a library using ts, and get some trouble when trying to extend core module type. Here is the project structure.

```
- src
  - core
    - core.ts
  - plugins
    - insert
      - index.ts
```

code in `core.ts`

```
export interface Commands {}

export class Core {
  commands: Commands;

  constructor() {
    this.commands = {};
  }

  registerCommands(name: string, func: any) {
    // @ts-ignore
    this.commands[name] = func;
  }
}
```

code in `insert/index.ts`

```
import { Core } from "../../core/core";

export class InsertPlugin {
  constructor(core: Core) {
    core.registerCommands("insert", this.insert.bind(this));
  }

  insert(value: string) {
    console.log("insert " + value);
  }
}
```

`InsertPlugin` using `core.registerCommands` to register a command `insert` to core.

My question is how can some one using my library get types for `insert` command. For example

```
// assume the name of the library is core
import { createCore } from 'core'

const core = createCore()
// How can i get types for insert method
core.commands.insert()
```

I have create a complete demo for above code, https://github.com/clinyong/ts-extends-core-commands.

Also I have read the typescript handbook for plugin types, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-plugin-d-ts.html.

Answer (score 1):

What's interesting with your example is that accessing `core.commands.insert()` is only valid *after* you create a `new InsertPlugin(core)` instance (which you don't do in your example).

Given this, you can actually encode this requirement if you were to use a function with an assertion return type, rather than a class.

`insert/index.ts`:

```
import { Core } from "../../core/core";

function registerInsertPlugin(core: Core): asserts core is (Core & {
  commands: {
    insert: typeof insert
  }
}) {

  const insert = (value: string) => {
    console.log("insert " + value);
  }

  core.registerCommands("insert", insert);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
import { createCore } from 'core'
import { registerInsertPlugin } from 'insert'

const core = createCore();
registerInsertPlugin(core);
core.commands.insert('hello world');
```

Forgetting to call `registerInsertPlugin` will result in a **valid** type error:

```
import { createCore } from 'core'

const core = createCore();
core.commands.insert('hello world');
// ^ Property 'insert' does not exist on type 'Commands'
```

Beyond this, you will then be able to also create multiple "plugins", each of which will expand `core.commands` with the relevant types:

```
const core = createCore();
registerInsertPlugin(core);
registerUpsertPlugin(core);
core.commands.insert('hello world');
core.commands.upsert("hello world");

/* Resulting Type:
 * const core: Core & {
 *     commands: {
 *         insert: (value: string) => void;
 *     };
 * } & {
 *     commands: {
 *         upsert: (value: string) => void;
 *     };
 * }
 */
```